# li anchor with iframe get index and change url

Tags: jquery, indexing, anchor, html-lists

I have a `div` with `ul` and `li` with `anchor` element and want to find out the index of element clicked

```
<div id="somediv">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="hello.com">Hello</a></li>
        <li><a href="world.com">world</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And below is the code i wrote but it doent worked out..
and how can we get the link of specific element clicked

```
$("#somediv ul li a").click(function(){
    alert($('a', this).index(this));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close, only made one little mistake. The JS should read:

```
$("#somediv ul li a").click(function(){
    alert($('a').index(this));
});​
```

You don't have to add `this`to the selection if you want to find the position of it inside the selection. See: http://api.jquery.com/index/

See a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VwKGC/1/

Answer (score 0):

Here you go man!

```
$("#somediv ul li a").click(function(){
var k = $(this).parent().index();
alert(k);

});​
```